# Possible number of combinations

Tags: combinations

me and a buddy were talking today and started discussing possible combinations of character builds within our game we are creating.  We decided that there would be three core upgradeable attributes to a player.

1.) Jumping Ability 
2.) Speed
3.) Strength

When the game starts all of these abilities will be at 0. As the player progresses, they will be able to upgrade each of these abilities 5 times. So each abilities will have 6 possible states:

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

Now we are trying to figure out the possible combinations of these three abilities.

We started by looking at all possible outcomes as if they were a 3 bit sequence:

000,
001,
010,
011,
100,
101,
110,
111.

This was good, but that would mean that each ability only had 2 states, 0 or 1.  As described before, this is not what we want. We want each to have 6 possible states.  We began to make a list, but it got out of control fast... Is there an easy way to compute this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May I suggest $6^3=216$?

Comment: Yeah you can suggest that, is it correct? Any do you know of anywhere that I can see a visual of every possible combination?

Comment: Yes! The first has six choices. For each such choice the next has six choices making this $6\cdot 6$ possibilities for the first two. For each configuration of the first two the last has six choices. So $6\cdot 6\cdot 6=6^3=216$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jumping ability may be one of $6$ values; speed may be one of $6$ values; strength may be one of $6$ values. Each ability is independent of the other, so there are $(6)(6)(6)=6^3=216$ combinations.